# MySQL: Select orders that have completed lines

Tags: mysql

This has got to be simple.

I have two tables: ORDERS and ORDER_LINES. Pretty simple and self-explanatory; it is a one-to-many relationship. ORDER_LINES has a FULFILLED column containing the date when that particular line was completed.

Here's what I need to do: select all ORDERS.ID of the orders that are complete; i.e. none of the FULFILLED columns in the ORDER_LINES table are NULL for that particular order.

Example:

Order #1 has two lines, both of which are not null

Order #2 has one line that is null

The query should only return #1 because it is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select *
From orders As O
Where Not Exists    (
                    Select 1
                    From order_lines As OL1
                    Where OL1.Fullfilled Is Null
                         And OL1.OrderId = O.OrderId
                    )
```

[SQL Fiddle version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09377/3)

An alternate version which uses the In function:

```
Select *
From orders As O
Where O.OrderId Not In    (
                          Select OL1.OrderId
                          From order_lines As OL1
                          Where OL1.Fullfilled Is Null
                          )
```

[SQL Fiddle version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09377/4)

**Addition**

There was a desire to accomplish this using an aggregate function. While below is a solution, the forms that use the Exists and In function express the intent much better than the following query and thus I'd recommend one of those two forms over:

```
Select O.OrderId
From Orders As O
    Left Join Order_Lines As OL
        On OL.OrderId = O.OrderId
            And OL.Fullfilled Is Null
Group By O.OrderId
Having Count(OL.Id) = 0
```

[SQL Fiddle version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09377/7)

Yet another form which likely would perform the best:

```
Select O.OrderId
From Orders As O
    Left Join Order_Lines As OL
        On OL.OrderId = O.OrderId
            And OL.Fullfilled Is Null
Where OL.Id Is Null
```

[SQL Fiddle version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09377/8)

Comment: Is there a 'cleaner', aggregate function that will do this instead of a nested SELECT?

Comment: @JFriend - Technically, yes there is a way to do it with an aggregate function but why would you want to do it that way? It won't express your intent nearly as well as the Exists or In functions.

Comment: I'm just thinking of overhead and resources on a very large database (16M order lines, 30 concurrent users).

Comment: @JFriend - My guess is that the form that uses the In function will perform the best but you'd have to check the execution plans to know for sure.

Comment: @JFriend - I take that back. Actually, the last form I just posted will probably be the fastest.

Comment: Thanks for your help; all your queries work well. I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use left join and add condition to query for selectiong only rows with not null in needed column. Like this.

```
SELECT ORDERS.ID 
FROM ORDERS 
LEFT JOIN ORDER_LINES 
    ON (ORDERS.ID = ORDER_LINES.ORDER_ID) 
WHERE ORDER_LINES.ORDER_ID is not null
```

Comment: This doesn't do it... you must check the fulfilled column to see if all of the lines [for each order] are completed.